# Generating an email with a QR code

Tags: qr-code, mailto

I am trying to generate QR codes for each of my customers. Each QR code would create an email to me. I've researched and I am pretty sure that I understand how to best create emails with a specific subject and body filled in.

1. Create the mailto code/script/line that would create the email.

mailto:test@gmail.com?subject=Test%20Subject&body=This%20is%20a%20test.

1. Create a tinyurl out of the script, to create a more reliable QR code.

http://tinyurl.com/nry2xud

1. Make a QR code out of it with any standard website. I used http://www.mobile-barcodes.com/qr-code-generator.

This is all fine, but I want the QR codes to mask the sender's email address. I do not want to get an email from a personal email account that the customer has on their phone. I want to replace their email address with the company address that the specific customer works for.

Is this possible? Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition, `mailto` uses whatever mail client is configured in the user's browser, and sends from their own email address. (From [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068): "Originator fields like From ... when present in the URI, MUST be ignored.")

If you have a web server somewhere, a better solution would be to avoid `mailto` entirely. Instead, have the QR code direct the user to a page on your server. The server script for that page (written in, say, PHP) would send you the email. Then, it would also serve up a confirmation message to the user.

Comment: I figured what I wanted to do would be impossible with only mailto. Thanks for the answer.